# R how to use formatStyle and styleValue to format a column based on multiple other columns

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, dt

I am trying to add a color bar to a datatable column where:

1. The size of the color bar is determined by the value in the
   column and
2. The color is determined on the color value stored in
   a different column.

I'm using a custom color bar function (styleColorBarAlt) because I can't get the text alignment that I need using the built-in styleColorBar.

[data table where valCol1 formatting is not working but valCol2 formatting is successful because I've used the string "#A9A9A9" for the color value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nptjj.png)

I have part 1 working but am stuck on part 2. If I just use a string for the color, it works fine (see valCol2), but I need each color bar to be colored based on the value in the color column.

```
    data <- data.frame(category=c("cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"),
                   valCol1=c(.1, .2, .3, .4), 
                   valCol2=c(.5, .6, .7, .8),
                   color=c("#007094","#FDE333","#4B0055","#00BE7D"))

#vAlternate style color bar function
styleColorBarAlt <- function (value1, value2)
{
  JS(sprintf("isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value == 1 ? 'linear-gradient(0deg, %s, %s 50%%, %s 50%% 100%%)': 'linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, transparent ' + (50-50*value) + '%%, %s ' + (50-50*value) + '%% ' + (50+50*value) + '%%, transparent ' + (50+50*value) + '%%)'",
             value2, value2, value2, value2))
}



datatable(data) %>%
  formatStyle(c(2),
              valueColumns = c(2,4),
              background = styleColorBarAlt(value1 = styleValue()[1], 
value2 = styleValue()[2]), # Pretty sure this is incorrect
              backgroundSize = '100% 100%',
              backgroundPosition = 'center center') %>%
  formatStyle(c(3),
              valueColumns = 3,
              background = styleColorBarAlt(value1 = data[,3], 
value2 = "#A9A9A9"), # Works fine if I use a string
              backgroundSize = '100% 100%',
              backgroundPosition = 'center center')
```

Answer (score 0):

With the columnwise option `render` you can use the data of a whole row. I don't understand your linear gradient (partly because your function does not depend on `value1`), so I show you an example with the font size and the color. You will have to adapt it to your colorbar.

```r
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  category = c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"),
  valCol1 = c(13, 16, 19, 22),
  valCol2 = c(.5, .6, .7, .8),
  color = c("#007094", "#FDE333", "#4B0055", "#00BE7D")
)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var fontSize = data + 'px';",
  "    var color = row[4];",
  "    data = '<span style=\"color: ' + color + '; font-size: ' + fontSize + ';\">' + data + '</span>';",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = 2, render = JS(render)),
      list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

---

Here is another technique. Create a list column which groups your two columns. I call it `hidden` because we will use it but hide it. Then the JavaScript `value` for this column is an array with two elements, and you can access them with `value[0]` and `value[1]`.

```r
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  category = c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"),
  valCol1 = c(13, 16, 19, 22),
  valCol2 = c(.5, .6, .7, .8),
  color = c("#007094", "#FDE333", "#4B0055", "#00BE7D")
)

hidden <- purrr::transpose(list(dat$valCol1, dat$color))
dat$hidden <- I(hidden)

datatable(
  dat, 
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = 5, visible = FALSE),
      list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
    )
  )
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    2, valueColumns = 5, 
    color = JS("value[1]"), fontSize = JS("value[0]") 
  )
```